# How add group of objects to database with incremented id?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need add group of objects to oracle database with new generated id for the group and set groupId field to each added records. Table looks like this: GR(objId number, groupId number). The problem is if I get max group Id before adding objects to database and then add them, then there is a problem with threading. Is there a way add it without problems with threading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a sequence.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE groupid_seq;
```

Before adding new records, fetch a new value from the sequence:

```
SELECT groupid_seq.nextval FROM dual;
```

Use this value as a groupId in the `INSERT`. Your database will handle that no thread will ever get a duplicate number.

Comment: What mean "dual" table name?

Comment: It's an Oracle builtin table with 1 record. It's useful for selecting a single value like `sysdate`, `user` or the next value of a sequence. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUAL_table